# Accessing session object during Unit test of Flask application

Tags: python, session, flask

I know it is possible to create session object using session_transaction() method. However, is there a way to access the current session object which gets created when for example "/" route gets hit? I did `from flask import session` to access the session but it's empty. Let me know if it is possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[This](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/#accessing-and-modifying-sessions) is what you're looking for. As it says however, you'd have to use the instantiation you create in your `with` statement.

```
with app.test_client() as c:
    with c.session_transaction() as sess:
        sess['a_key'] = 'a value'

    # once this is reached the session was stored
    result = app.test_client.get('/a_url')
    # NOT part of the 2nd context
```

Note that this won't work if you run your test within the scope of the `with c.session_transaction() as sess` statement, it needs to be run *after* that block.

Comment: For people like me who skimmed over the most important line in the docs: the reason why you need to run the test after the transaction block is because the modifications made to the `session` object are only written back to the actual client's session when the transaction is closed.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to read the session data written in your view from the test, one way is to mock the session view as a dict and verify the session in your test. Here's an example using [Python's unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#module-unittest.mock):

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, session, request

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "my secret key"

@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def index():
    session["username"] = request.form["username"]
    return "Username saved in session"
```

**test_index.py**

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from app import app


def test_index():
    with patch("app.session", dict()) as session:
        client = app.test_client()
        response = client.post("/", data={
            "username": "test"
        })
        assert session.get("username") == "test"
        assert response.data == b"Username saved in session"
```

You can use any mocking solution you prefer, of course.

Comment: This works great.  Though when changing `session` in the `with` block, make sure not to create a new dict (e.g., `session = {}`) because that breaks the patch.  I lost a lot of time debugging that so hopefully I save others some pain.